# Collapsing sidebar bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, grid-system

I'm new to Bootstrap and have a little problem with understanding how does the grid system works. 
Initially, I have the following code for a page with a sidebar:

```
    <div class="row"> 
  <div class="sidebar col-xs-3">
         <div class="well">   
         <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Navigation
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 5</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 6</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 7</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

         </div>
   </div>
    <div class= "main col-xs-9">
         <div class="well">body</div>   
    </div> 

  </div>
```

With the following css:

```
/* Sidebar Styles */
.sidebar-nav {
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background: none;
}
```

It works fine on big screens while having the following problem on small screen size:
[image]

I would highly appreciate any explanation about why the sidebar text is not resizing right to the sidebar area?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by using different classes for sidebar and body

```
<div class="sidebar col-md-3 col-xs-6">

</div>
<div class= "main col-md-9 col-xs-6">
     <div class="well">body</div>   
</div>
```